# Vue: When to register component in main.js vs in the .vue file

Tags: vue.js

Say I have a basic vue project

main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import SomeComponent from './components/SomeComponent.vue';

const app = createApp(App);
app.component('some-component', SomeComponent);
app.mount('#app');
```

components/App.vue:

```
<template>
  <some-component></some-component>
</template>

<script>
import SomeComponent from "./SomeComponent.vue";

export default {
  components: { SomeComponent },
};
</script>
```

components/SomeComponent.vue:

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
```

Note that in `main.js`, I call `app.component('some-component', SomeComponent);` and in `SomeComponent.vue` I also specify the same with `components: { SomeComponent },`. Only one of the two ways is needed (though specifying both doesn't seem to cause errors).

My question is this: When would you specify components in `main.js` instead of in the component that will actually use it?

It seems that I could create an entire storefront and list all of the components in `main.js` without ever using `components: {}` inside a single one of my components and it would work. But it seems more logical to me to list the used sub-components inside each component that will use them for the encapsulation and reusability it brings. But that's because I have an object oriented mindset.

Comment: If you have a large application and a lot of basic components (like custom buttons, for example) - it would be tedious to import and register them in every `.vue` file where they are used. IF you register them in `main.js` it will save you some (or a lot) of typing. On the other hand, when you list the used components in the corresponding sub-component - it is easier to visually determine the dependency between components. But I think that the latter is not so important.

Comment: "it is easier to visually determine the dependency between components. But I think that the latter is not so important". Playing devil's advocate: Why not? If you have it in the component that uses it, you can rest assured that that component is "complete" and not dependent on your main.js. I see your point but I'm not quite sure where you would draw the line. Like, would you register EVERYTHING in main.js?

Comment: No, I certainly won't register EVERYTHING in `main.js` - only those sub-components which are repeatedly used in more than 40% of my main components.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Meanwhile I've found out that webpack inserts the global imports into every single component even if it doesn't use it, bloating the resulting js file. So it's a matter of convenience vs performance and readability then.

Comment: Webpack uses "tree-shaking" to remove unused code - are you sure that this bloating is not caused by async components?

Comment: By "found out" I mean that I read it in a few places. But I haven't inspected the output of webpack yet to confirm it.

Comment: Sometimes a component which is used by several other **async** components will end up duplicated in each of these **async** components.